# R flextable automatic row height adjustment (hrule) not working for PDF output

Tags: pdf, r-markdown, flextable

I'm trying to display several tables where the column widths are the same but the row heights vary with the amount of data in the cells in a PDF document generated from an .Rmd file. Despite explicitly setting the column widths and font sizes, and using `hrule(rule="auto", part="all")` to let the row heights vary, the output changes the widths and font sizes to keep the row heights the same.

Contents of the .Rmd:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r, echo=FALSE, collapse=TRUE, include=FALSE}
# Load libraries
#webshot::install_phantomjs() # needed for flextable. Don't need to load it as a package.
library(dplyr) # data management
library(flextable) # produce tables
library(OpenRepGrid) # generate random words

# Build data
table1Df <- data_frame(item = paste0(1:5, "."),
                       labels = c(randomSentence(10),
                                  randomSentence(10),
                                  randomSentence(10),
                                  randomSentence(10),
                                  randomSentence(10)
                                  ),
                       score = 11:15
                       )

table2Df <- data_frame(item = paste0(1:5, "."),
                       labels = c(randomSentence(15),
                                  randomSentence(15),
                                  randomSentence(15),
                                  randomSentence(15),
                                  randomSentence(15)
                                  ),
                       score = 16:20
                       )

# Function to build flextable
flexPrintFun <- function(df){
  flextable(df) %>%
    width(j=1, width=0.25) %>%
    width(j=2, width=3) %>%
    width(j=3, width=0.5) %>%
    hrule(rule="auto", part="all") %>%
    fontsize(part="header", size=20) %>%
    fontsize(part="body", size=15) 
}
```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
flexPrintFun(table1Df)
flexPrintFun(table2Df)
```
````

Here's what it ends up looking like (after zooming in quite a bit because the columns get crushed way down):

[image]

The final document will have the tables stacked on top of each other, so it's important that the column widths line up, font sizes are consistent, etc.

I've looked into the documentation about `hrule` here: https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/reference/hrule.html and while it states that it works in Word and HTML but not PowerPoint outputs, it says nothing about PDF.

I've looked into `kable` and `kableExtra` but those don't quite do everything I need with some other features I don't discuss here.

Comment: You perhaps need webshot2 instead of webshot. See first 2 paragraphs of the help file here: https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/articles/offcran/images.html

Comment: @DavidGohel I went ahead and updated to R 4.0.0 for a fresh start and installed webshot2. Turns out `OpenRepGrid` (to generate the random text) installs webshot anyway. PDF output is still the same, though the row heights do seem to adjust when they appear in the .Rmd when running the code blocks. When I uninstall webshot and plug text in manually, I get an "error loading PDF" message.